# CSS filter composed of multiple SVG filters makes image darker

Tags: css, svg-filters, css-filters

I can apparently chain a sequence of css filters
together by simply concatenating them,
which seems to work:

```
  filter: brightness(200%) brightness(200%);
```

But when the individual filters in question are svg filters,
it seems to make the resulting image unexpectedly darker for some reason:

```
  filter: url(#myIdentityFilter) url(#myIdentityFilter);
```

The following image shows this effect (it's from the snippet at the bottom of this post, on chrome 103.0.5060.134):

[image: output of the code snippet]

I've observed this unexpected darkening with many kinds
of svg filters, e.g. feComponentTransfer, feColorMatrix, feDiffuseLighting.

@HolgerL mentions this darkening problem in a comment on [Multiple Filters for Single Object in SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338380/multiple-filters-for-single-object-in-svg#answer-63959036) (where the method was suggested, in the context of svg
rather than html; apparently the same problem happens there too).

Should chaining like this work?
I know I can work around the darkening problem, in order to achieve the desired effect,
by nesting my element inside a container div,
and applying the second filter to the container div
instead of chaining it on to the first filter;
this is similar to what was suggested
in [Multiple Filters for Single Object in SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14338380/multiple-filters-for-single-object-in-svg#answer-14340002) .
That works.

But I'd like to use the simpler more concise chaining syntax if possible.

The above image was produced by the following snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style>
      .gradientSwatch {
        display:inline-block;
        width:64px;
        height:64px;
        background-image:linear-gradient(black, white);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body style="background:#aaaaaa;">
    <svg width="0" height="0"> <!-- NOT display:none, which would make filters invisible -->
      <filter id="identity">
        <feComponentTransfer>
          <!-- no funcs, so should be the identity -->
        </feComponentTransfer>
      </filter>
    </svg>
    <hr>
    increasing numbers of brightness(200%) (seems correct):
    <br>
    0: <div class="gradientSwatch"></div>
    1: <div class="gradientSwatch" style="filter:brightness(200%);"></div>
    2: <div class="gradientSwatch" style="filter:brightness(200%) brightness(200%);"></div>
    3: <div class="gradientSwatch" style="filter:brightness(200%) brightness(200%) brightness(200%);"></div>
    <hr>
    increasing numbers of brightness(100%) (seems correct):
    <br>
    0: <div class="gradientSwatch"></div>
    1: <div class="gradientSwatch" style="filter:brightness(100%);"></div>
    2: <div class="gradientSwatch" style="filter:brightness(100%) brightness(100%);"></div>
    3: <div class="gradientSwatch" style="filter:brightness(100%) brightness(100%) brightness(100%);"></div>
    <hr>
    increasing numbers of url(#identity) (gets unexpectedly darker when 2 or more):
    <br>
    0: <div class="gradientSwatch"></div>
    1: <div class="gradientSwatch" style="filter:url(#identity);"></div>
    2: <div class="gradientSwatch" style="filter:url(#identity) url(#identity);"></div>
    3: <div class="gradientSwatch" style="filter:url(#identity) url(#identity) url(#identity);"></div>
    <hr>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was running into the same issue and chanced upon this somewhat related answer for [SVG Filter: Different colouring depending on browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56032185/17799081). It seems that the `color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"` property could be added to each filter to fix the behavior.

I've tried on Chrome with the below and saw that without the property, darkening occurs, with the property, the image is normal.

Not sure why the behavior is like that, but this may unblock you.

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/a0bs8oJ.jpeg"/>

<svg>
  <defs>
    <filter id="f1" primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feFlood in="SourceGraphic" x="0.70" y="0.1" width="0.15" height="0.25" />
      <feComposite operator="in" in="SourceGraphic"/>
      <feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="0"/>
      <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
    <filter id="f2" primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <feFlood in="SourceGraphic" x="0.25" y="0.4" width="0.25" height="0.35" />
      <feComposite operator="in" in="SourceGraphic"/>
      <feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="0"/>
      <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

```css
img {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  filter: url(#f1) url(#f2)
}
```

Comment: Yes, I had discovered that too and had not got around to mentioning it here.  This is apparently the secret sauce that makes this work completely :-)  Accepting